# runtime error: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, classnotfoundexception

I am new to mysql and jdbc and I am getting the error in this title. I have been searching all day and cannot find a solution that works for me.

What I have tried:
uninstall/reinstall mysql, copy paste mysql-connector-java-5.1.25-bin.jar and ojdbc7.jar to same location as the .class file I am trying to run, rebuilt the program in a different directory, and probably a couple other things.

I am using notepad++ for coding and the windows command prompt to compile and run. it compiles fine but I try to run with

> C:\Projects\bin>java -cp . ClientBase

The output is:

> java.lang.ClassnNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
>
> > at java.net.URLClassloader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:336) 
> >     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355) 
> >     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) 
> >     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354) 
> >     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:432) 
> >     at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308) 
> >     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356) 
> >     at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) 
> >     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:188) 
> >     at ClientBase.main(ClientBase.java:21) 
> >     Goodbye.

```
// import packages
import java.sql.*;

// create class ClientBase
public class ClientBase{
            // JDBC driver name and database URL
            static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";                
            static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/CLIENTBASE";          



 // Database credentials
    static final String USER = "root";
    static final String PASS = "";

// Begin method main
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Connection conn = null;
    Statement stmt = null;

    try{
        // register JDBC driver
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

        // Open connection
        System.out.println("Connecting to database...");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);

        // Execute a query
        System.out.println("Creating statement...");
        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        String sql;
        sql = "SELECT id, name, address, address 2, city, phone, state, zip, fax FROM CLIENTBASE";
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

        // Extract data from result set
        while(rs.next()){
            // Retrieve by column name
            int id = rs.getInt("id");
            String name = rs.getString("name");
            String address = rs.getString("address");
            String address2 = rs.getString("address2");
            String city = rs.getString("city");
            String phone = rs.getString("phone");
            String state = rs.getString("state");
            String zip = rs.getString("zip");
            String fax = rs.getString("fax");

            // Display values
            System.out.print("ID: " + id);
            System.out.print(" Name: " + name);
            System.out.println("Address:" + address);
            System.out.println(address2);
            System.out.print("City:" + city);
            System.out.print(" State: " + state);
            System.out.println(" Zip: " + zip);
            System.out.print("Phone: " + phone);
            System.out.println(" Fax: " + fax);
        } // end while

        // clean up
        rs.close();
        stmt.close();
        conn.close();
    }catch(SQLException se){
        // Handle errors for JDBC
        se.printStackTrace();
    }catch(Exception e){
        // Handle errors for Class.forName
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally{
        // finally block used to close resources
        try{
            if(stmt!=null)
                stmt.close();
        }catch(SQLException se){
            se.printStackTrace();
        } // end finally
    } // end try
System.out.println("Goodbye.");
} // End method main
} // end class ClientBase
```

I should also say that I am going off an online tutorial for this code. It is not exactly how they have it as I decided to make something a little different than theirs, but it is generally the same. I don't think it is a code problem though from what the error is.

Any help would be appreciated! I'm going crazy!

Comment: Can you post folder hierarchy?

Comment: `// finally block used to close resources` - really ? so why you are closing them in try ? Also try to format your code !!!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to add a connector library to the Runtime classpath:

```
java -cp .;mysql-connector-java-5.1.25-bin.jar ClientBase
```

My example uses Windows classpath separator `";"`, on other systems it may be different (`":"` on Linux/Mac). It also assumes, that `mysql-connector-java-5.1.25-bin.jar` is located on the same folder. If it's not the case, then put a path to the library instead of the plain name.

`ClientBase` stands for Java class file name here

```
c:\>javac Test.java
c:\>java -cp .;F:\CK\JavaTest\JDBCTutorial\mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin Test
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked! I saw this same answer with other posts but I was was not understanding it from them and was typing it in wrong by adding a semi-colon after the jar and the full class path to ClientBase.

Comment: i also get same problem :-  
i get the file and the paste it to the same folder where my class file is saved then run the following command in my linux  
java -cp .:mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin.jar FirstExample

Comment: I am running project through NetBeans, how do i configure it "default" so that i don't have to pass the command line argument everytime?

Comment: Tanks for the clarification about the difference between ";" and ":" it was causing me troubles.

Answer (score 3):

`I was also get same problem :-`
How I solved  for **Linux system**.

**1.)** Download file [mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin.jar](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCgQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fcode.google.com%2Fp%2Ffind-ur-pal%2Fdownloads%2Fdetail%3Fname%3Dmysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin.jar%26&ei=RkbjU5vYO8eSuASOsIFg&usg=AFQjCNGKExb1ZRnGFrEw8eNd32c_O1YybA&bvm=bv.72676100,d.c2E) from given link or other.

**2.)** Then paste it to same folder or directory of your class or file (on where you want connection to present)

**3.)** Now use the following command by your linux command prompt.

`java -cp .:mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin.jar YourFileName` ..

Thats all you need to do... :)

Answer (score 2):

if u use netbeans,do following
    1.Open Netbeans IDE
    2.Right-click your Project.
    3.Select Properties.
    4.On the left-hand side click Libraries.
    5.Under "Compile" tab - click Add Jar/Folder button.
    6.Select Downloaded "mysql-connector-java-5.1.25-bin.jar" file (Download Connector/J from dev.mysql.com)
    7.Click OK
    Run Again... Its work.

Answer (score 1):

What did you import ?
From the documentation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-usagenotes-connect-drivermanager.html

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
// Notice, do not import com.mysql.jdbc.*
// or you will have problems!
```

Comment:

Why are you using notepad++ ? install an IDE (Eclipse/Netbeans/IntelliJ) - it'll be much easier to locate such problems (un-included jars for example)

Answer (score 1):

Add `mysql.connector-java-x.x.x-bin.jar` to your libraries folder. No need to import anything. Have a good one.

Answer (score 0):

If You Are Using `Swing`  you have to add External Jar of [my-sql-connect](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/com.mysql/com.mysql.jdbc_5.1.5.jar.zip)

else if You are Using `jsp servlet` You have to add External jar and Copy that Jar into *WEB_INF/lib* project folder