# On other pc java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlserver

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, driver

I wrote an app and it works fine by me. But on other pc-s it throws an exception.

> java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlserver

I give it (only the app.jar file) to my college, and he gets this error. I give him a jdbcdriver.jar file and, nothing changed.
However I use jre7, I added a line to the code:

```
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
```

And than he gets another exception:

> Error: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

What can I do to run this app properly on other pc-s?

Comment: You need to google sometimes before posting your query. Atleast we will all know that you have put some efforts. Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17484764/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-com-mysql-jdbc-driver-in-eclipse and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18158864/runtime-error-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-com-mysql-jdbc-driver

Comment: you need to use the driver.jar in the classpath. If you are running through command line, use >java Main -classpath "driver.jar"

Comment: Why are you loading the MySQL driver when you want to connect to SQL Server?

Comment: Can I connect to sql server without using mysql driver?

Answer (score 0):

Put the jar file, containing the `MySql Driver` on the `classpath` when starting your application.

The switch is called `-cp` or `-classpath` like this:

```
java -cp ".;mysql.jar" my.package.Main
```

assuming you start your application from the root directory which is named `my.package.Main`. The classpath separator is the one for `Windows`. For unix based OSs you need to use `:` i guess.

Comment: What sould I put instead of my.package.Main

eg.: my app path is:

D:\app.jar

this is not enough:

java -cp D:\mysql-connector-java-5.1.23-bin.jar d:TCfinder.jar

Comment: What is the fully qualified name of your class containing the `public static void main(String[] args)` method? Use that fully qualified name instead.

Comment: TCfinder is my main class

Comment: I set "java -cp D:\mysql-connector-java-5.1.23-bin.jar TCfinder -jar D\:TCfinder.jar "

and I still get Error: Could not find or load main class TCfinder

Comment: You may try: `java -cp "D:\mysql-connector-java-5.1.23-bin.jar" -jar D\:TCfinder.jar` instead or `java -cp "D:\mysql-connector-java-5.1.23-bin.jar;D\:TCfinder.jar" TCfinder`.

Comment: java -cp "D:\mysql-connector-java-5.1.23-bin.jar" -jar D:\TCfinder.jar D:\sf.c 149
    There are 2 aguments in the end.

Comment: and this: java -cp "D:\mysql-connector-java-5.1.23-bin.jar; D:\TCfinder.jar D:\sf.c 149" TCfinder do not work either, could not find or load main class TCfidner

Comment: How did you started your main class in the first place? Before I posted my answer?

Comment: public class TCfinder {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception { ...

Comment: I meant which command have you used to start it (in the console / command line interface)?

Comment: oh, I start it form ultraedit,it's a tool and this is the command:
java -jar D:\TCfinder.jar %f %line%

Comment: The answer was really easy:
the jdbc.jar file should be in a lib folder next to the app.jar file.
eg.:
d:\application\app.jar
d:\application\lib\jdbc_driver.jar

And start it is simple:
java -jar d:\application\app.jar

Thanks for all the answers!