# While calling the below function control is going to the first line inside try block i.e to Class.forName then to catch block

Tags: java, jdbc

```
   package com.java.bean;

   import java.sql.Connection;
   import java.sql.DriverManager;
   import java.sql.ResultSet;
   import java.sql.Statement;

   public class Dao {

      // static  Connection con = null;
    static ResultSet rs = null;
    static String url ="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/first";
    static String user = "root";
    static String passsword = "password";
    public static Ex1 login(Ex1 ex){
    try{
        //System.out.println("iam in first line");
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.driver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url,user,passsword);
        String userName = ex.getUserName();
        String password = ex.getPassword();
        Statement st =  con.createStatement();
           rs = st.executeQuery("Select * from employee where username = " +userName +"and password =" +password ); 
           boolean  more = rs.next();
           if(!more)
           {
            System.out.println("you are not a registered user!");
            ex.setValid(false);
           }
           else if(more)
           {
            System.out.println("welcome MR.HImanshu you are Great"); 
            ex.setValid(true);
           }

    }
    catch(Exception tex)
    {
        System.out.println("hey there is an exception " +ex);
    }
    return ex;
    }
   }
```

Comment: Have you added the mysql driver library to your built path ?

Comment: yes i ahve added it to the build path

Comment: actually i have tried to check whether the class.forname is working fine or not by writing one of the class inside which i wrote a main function and registered the driver and wrote the select querry and got the retrieved resultset

Comment: possible duplicate of [runtime error: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18158864/runtime-error-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-com-mysql-jdbc-driver)

Comment: i have written it with small d but now changed to D , still not working

Comment: WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:Himanshu' did not find a matching property.

Comment: Can you post the stack trace of the exception, you can get it by adding this line`tex.printStackTrace();`  in the `catch` block

Comment: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Comment: why i am getting this error bcz i have added to the build path

Comment: Take a look at the content of the library, see if it has a `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` class, maybe you've added a wrong one.

Comment: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
 at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1305)
 at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1157)

Comment: It looks like you are using Tomcat, if so, you need to edit your "context.xml" file and get a database connection using a `DataSource` object, [more details here](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html)

Comment: yes i am using tomcat now how i can get a connection and what i should write in context.xml

Comment: actually i can see the web.xml file inside web-inf but where is context.xml

Comment: More details here https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html

Answer (score 1):

Is

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
```

not

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.driver");
```

"Driver" with an uppercase "D".